# The map color display in GEE and QGIS is different

Tags: qgis, google-earth-engine, qgis-processing, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, colormap

I'm new to in Google Earth Engine and QGIS. Lately I try to export map from Google Earth Engine and then i opened the map in qgis. Sadly, the map color in Google Earth Engine is not the same in QGIS. How to solve it?

[image]

Comment: When loading a layer into QGIS it will assign a random color to the newly added layer. After liad8ng the layer you need to apply a style.

Comment: @GforGIS how to do it?

Comment: In what format are your layers? KML ? KMZ?

Comment: You can follow this tutorial for vectors: https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/basic_vector_styling.html Or this one for rasters: https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/raster_styling_and_analysis.html .